# Websocket configuration doesn't work in nginx 1.18.0 on ubuntu 20.04 (AWS EC2)

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

[image]

[image]

Websocket connection is closed in 60s if I don't do any action in chat.

I tried to increase the timeout with `proxy_*_timeout` but failed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: I made app ping in every 30 seconds and it resolved the problem.